# Uncommitted changes in Master immediately after checking Master out in sourcetree

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a forked a repo on GitHub. I have a master on this fork so that I can branch features separately and do pull requests to the upstream/master per feature. The only time my master changes is when the origin changes, meaning I don't merge my features into my master. I have updated my master from the origin and I now need to merge those changes into one of my feature branches.

The problem I am encountering is that I seem to have about 40 Unstaged files in my master branch. There appears to be 2 to 3 of each file marked: ~Automatic Revision, ~HEAD, or ~HEAD_0.
*I am not terribly familiar with Git, though the basic concepts seem to be straight forward. I think most of my issues are me not understanding how sourcetree works.*

First, Why would there be Unstaged/Uncommitted changes immediately after checking out my master?

Second, How can I be sure I am merging a complete copy of my master to my feature branch so that I am not unnecessarily altering files that are not part of my feature changes while issuing my pull request from my feature branch back to the upstream/master?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by deleting and re-cloning master branch.